# How to set a custom context for NanMakeCallback->Call

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, node.js-addon, node.js-nan

NAN 1.7.0 introduced an optional `target` parameter for `NanCallbackCall`. This parameter allows you to set the context for the callback i.e. `this`.

However not matter what I do the `this` value in my JavaScript callback is always the default `Global` context. I would expect the following to make `foo` available on `this` in my JavaScript callback.

```
Local<Object> context = NanNew<Object>();
context->Set(NanNew<String>("foo"), NanNew<String>("bar"));
myNanCallback->Call(context, argv_v8.size(), &argv_v8[0]);
```